# Highlight words inside the string

Tags: jquery, css, string, highlight

I got certain string, and I want to highlight the substring typed in the text input.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rFGWZ/17/

It is working fine only , when I type the initial string, but when I type fe. `15` in the input, it doesn't highlight the `15` but `21` instead... it is always highlighting the numbers at the beggining, so could someone help me modify it, so it will highlight the string I type in the text input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
firstCell.html(id.replace(value, '<span class=highlight>'+value+'</span>'));
```

instead of

```
firstCell.html($("<span />").addClass("highlight").text(id.slice(0, value.length)));
firstCell.append(id.slice(value.length, id.length));
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qgBt8/

EDIT : [case insensitive version](http://jsfiddle.net/SVgL4/)

Comment: Is there a way, to make it case-insensitive, because in case if there would be some letters, it highlights those with case-sensivity. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression to solve this. This also takes into account case of characters.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFGWZ/20/)

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);
            var firstCell = $row.children("td:first");

            var id = $row.children("td:first").text();
            if (id.indexOf(value) === -1) {
                $row.children("td:first").text(id);
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                var re = new RegExp(value, "g"); //global replace
                firstCell.html(id.replace(re, "<span class=\"highlight\">" + value + "</span>"));//replace all instances of the characters
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Sure, but it still doesn't support case-insensitive characters, when there is `M` and `m` in the string and I would type `m` in the text input, then it will only highlight `m` instead of both ones.

Comment: I was not aware that you needed it to be case in-sensitive. Looks like you got your answer already!