# Add selection to range in jquery

Tags: jquery, range, selection

I have a problem. For example I have a `<div id="id">Helloworld</div>`. And now I want to select (for example) 5th to 9th word. So, I want to have Hello`worl`d ("worl" is hightlighted). Any ideas, how to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459734/highlight-words-inside-the-string

Comment: Is it dynamic? If not, why not just wrap those letters in a span: `<div id="id">Hello<span>worl</span>d</div>`

Comment: Yes, it is dynamic. I need exactly word selection.

Answer (score 1):

Collect the innerHTML using `.html()` or `.text()`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="id">Helloworld</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
  var myText = $("#id").html();
  var newText = myText.slice(0,5) + "<span class='highlight'>" + myText.slice(5,9) + "</span>" + myText.slice(9);
  $("#id").html(newText);
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/t0yu8pce/

**Update**

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/t0yu8pce/2/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var myText = $("#id").html();
  var newText = myText.slice(0, 5) + "<input value='" + myText.slice(5, 9) + "' />" + myText.slice(9);
  $("#id").html(newText);
  $("#highlight").click(function(e) {
    $("#id input:text").select();
  })
});
```

The text to select has to be in a `<input>` or `<textbox>` element.

**Update 2**

Using click: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/t0yu8pce/3/

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to highlight that text, as you can do with your cursor.

Comment: @VojtěchRemiš you didn't mention that. What would trigger this?

Comment: I thought select() works only in an input. It is triggered by div click.

Comment: @VojtěchRemiš provided updates to answer. Yes, it has to be a input or textbox.

Comment: And if it would be a textbox, can I select just (for example) 5th to 7th letters?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure If this is what you want but you can use `<mark>` or use `<span>` with appropriate style property.

As in your case:

```
<div id="id">Hello<mark style="background-color: #f0f0f5">wor</mark>ld</div>
```

Or do it this way

```
<div id="id">Hello<span style="background-color: #f0f0f5;font-weight:bold">wor</span>ld</div>
```

Comment: I want highlight that letters, like text selection, which you can select with your cursor.

Comment: @VojtěchRemiš You didn't mention that early. Check my other answer that I have posted.

Comment: I am not sure exactly, which answer do you think?

Comment: @VojtěchRemiš . The below posted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44397592/7201256